# How to convert Map<Key1Type, Val1Type> to Map<Key1Type, Val2Type>

Tags: java

Want to convert as per the method signature below.

```
Map<A, Set<B>> convert(Map<A, List<B>> original){
   original.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
            return new SimpleImmutableEntry(entry.getKey(), new HashSet<>(entry.getValue()));
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
}
```

Its giving me compiling issue not sure why. All am doing is transforming entry to intermediate entry of `Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>` and than collecting.

Comment: What is the language of the "compilation issue"?

Comment: Your method does not have `return` and is missing `<>` for `new SimpleImmutableEntry<>`

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.student;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MapConversion {

    static Map < String, Set < String >> convert(Map < String, List < String >> map1) {

        return map1.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e - > new HashSet(e.getValue())));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List < String > list1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
            "a",
            "b"
        });
        Map < String, List < String >> map1 = new HashMap < > () {
            {
                put("strin1", Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                    "a",
                    "a"
                }));
                put("strin2", Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                    "d",
                    "d"
                }));
                put("strin3", Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                    "e",
                    "f"
                }));
            }
        };

        System.out.println(convert(map1));

    }
}
```